# Able to deploy Spring-boot project on IDE but not Tomcat. Unable to find index.html

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have been at this for a few days now. Once I tried to integrate my application into Spring-Boot I started to run into all kinds of issues. I worked out but not I cannot deploy it on tomcat via `war` file. On my IDE it works fine - and I have tried deploying it to tomcat via my IDE and terminal by manually placing it in Tomcat with no success.

Pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.stidham.financial.StidhamFinancialBootApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resume
spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

server.port=8081
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/*
server.contextPath=/
```

main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.stidham.financial.config,com.stidham.financial.controller," +
        "com.stidham.financial.model,com.stidham.financial.repository,com.stidham.financial.services")
public class StidhamFinancialBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StidhamFinancialBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<StidhamFinancialBootApplication> applicationClass = StidhamFinancialBootApplication.class;
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WebConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/fonts/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/images/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/image/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/image/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/_sample/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/_sample/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/javascripts/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/javascripts/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/templates/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/templates/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/libs/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/libs/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet(){
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();

        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        return dispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Nothing appears to be loading therefore this tells me it cannot find my index.html.

[image]

I have uploaded the project on GIT https://github.com/drewjocham/SpringBootStidham.git

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put all your web content in src/main/resources/static.  That's where Tomcat expects to find static web content like index.html.

Comment: True and I did try that however I did define it in my application where it was going to be. I have literally done this same setup in a project and it worked fine. I do not know what is going on. I added a picture of my project directory.

Comment: @Drew1208 There is noting in your https://github.com/drewjocham/SpringBootStidham.git GIT Repo. May be you have marked it private or forgot to push the local commit.

Comment: @SanjayRawat https://github.com/drewjocham/SpringBootStidham.git is now uploaded. Sorry.

Comment: Why are you trying so hard NOT to use Spring Boot... With all the configuration and overrides you do you could as well not use Spring Boot. Why aren't you working with the framework instead of trying to work around the framework.

Comment: See my pull request with all the commits explaining the things to remove and move. It comes down to working with the framework and understand what it does for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I seen your request and accepted it. However it does not run on Tomcat (404 error) and in my IDE I get an error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext`

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry I manually deployed it to tomcat and it worked. However my intellij IDE is being funny. Thank you for the help

Comment: I did remove all the stuff that you shouldn't have committed in the first place, you might want to try importing it again. And understand the different commits and why you don't need most of what you did.

Comment: I got it all working. Thank for the help. I was pretty shocked at all the stuff you took out and it still worked.